# How can i create something like reverse loop in python with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops

i have a class named `myx` and in `myx` i have a variable named `_LEVELS`
i want to do reverse loop in reverse and make some string that's like this -> "`LEVEL3(LEVEL2(LEVEL1(inp),inp),LEVEL1(inp),inp)`"
i want this string example "**(LEVEL#(LEVEL#()))**" can be continue and finish when see `LEVEL1(inp)`

because the algoritm is this

LEVEL1(x1) -> x1=inp

LEVEL2(x1,x2) -> x1=LEVEL1(inp) x2=inp

LEVEL3(x1,x2,x3) -> x1=LEVEL2(LEVEL1(inp),inp) x2=LEVEL1(inp) x3=inp

and i want i could have LEVEL1000 or more but i cannot and i dont know how to write this code please Help me.

```
#/bin/python3
class myx:
    def __init__(self,...):
        self._max = 10
        self._LEVELS = []
    def set_data(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self._LEVELS.append(LEVEL[i])

    def _input_from(self,input,frm=None,to=-1):
        if frm == None:
            frm = 1
        if to == -1:
            to = self._max
        levels = self._LEVELS
        levels.reverse()
        output = ""
        # read levels and set them in a string
        # like : output += 'LEVEL3(' then in another loop output += 'LEVEL2(' and ....
        return output
```

i really confused my brain is dying for thinking of a algorithm for fix this and write it

i tried to do loop in loop i mean something like this

```
myloop = "for i{} in range({},{}):"
s = '\n\t'
x = s
temp = myloop+s

for i in range(myx._max):
    temp += myloop+s
    s+=x
then i tried to set this loop but i couldnt please help me
```

Comment: You should start with a more basic question (mostly to yourself). It goes... How should I write a question so that people will understand what I'm asking and be able to answer it?

Comment: Your code uses  `frm`, `to` , `input` (bad name -- is already used natively!), but how does that relate to the string you want to produce? That second snippet is creating a completely different string, not with "LEVEL", but with some Python syntax ("for i{}..."). I have absolutely no idea how that relates to your question.